# Matplotlib Histogram with no lines between the bars

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a histogram with matplotlib that has lines delineating the histogram, but with no lines between the bars. Something like this:

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`plt.hist()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html), you need to create the histogram using the argument `histtype="stepfilled"` and set the `edgecolor` of the patches, which is by default set to None, in order to get the histogram the way you desire:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.randn(10000)

plt.hist(data, histtype="stepfilled", edgecolor='k', linewidth=1.2)
```

[image]